# Listening to updates to activities in serverside C# code

Tags: c#, server-side, getstream-io

I'm experimenting with the getstream.io service, and evaluating if it fits our use case. Basically what I would like to to is for one server side service to add activity to a feed, and then for *another* server side code to subscribe to changes to that feed, and receive them in real time. Both should be in C# ideally.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible, you can add a [webhook](https://getstream.io/docs/realtime_backend/?language=js#webhooks) from the dashboard which will get the update as soon as there is a change in the feed.

If you're on AWS, you can copy updates to your [SQS](https://getstream.io/docs/realtime_backend/?language=js).

Moreover, [Faye](https://faye.jcoglan.com/) is also used for real-time updates. You can find a client for it in C# but it won't officially be supported (we're supporting it in JS SDK for example).